# Python request, succeed login, and then logout in different url

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

here my code :

```
session = requests.Session()

headers =  {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0', 
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0'} 

def generating_data():

    main_url='https://opencorporates.com/users/sign_in'    
    r1 = session.get(main_url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r1.text, 'html.parser')
    
    tokens = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name':'csrf-token'})
    token = tokens.get('content')
    print(f'token is : {token}')

    print('Login!')
    datas = {
        'utf8': '✓',
        'authenticity_token': token,
        'user[email]':'user',
        'user[password]':'pass',
        'submit':''
    }

    r2 = session.post('https://opencorporates.com/users/sign_in',headers=headers, data=datas, cookies=r1.cookies)
    r3 = session.get('https://opencorporates.com/companies?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=above+and+beyond&commit=Go&jurisdiction_code=&utf8=%E2%9C%93&commit=Go&nbsp=&controller=searches&action=search_companies&inactive=false&mode=best_fields&search_fields[]=name&branch=false&nonprofit=&order=score', headers=headers, cookies=r1.cookies)

    f = open('./res.html', 'w+')
    f.write(r3.text)
    f.close

generating_data()
```

i already get the result of login if print the r2 line, but when change to next line r3, it show the page like we are not login yet, anyone can help ? thanks

Comment: Can you show more detail. What `r3` response?  `401`, `400`?

Comment: all status code is 200.. the problem is they show us the non login page..

Comment: in your r3 line, remove the portion `cookies=r1.cookies` since your are already using sessions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the portion `cookies=r1.cookies` since you are already using a session. What this does is it overwrites the cookies collected from response of `r2` that would have been sent along with the request, and which might been important for logging in. Same goes for the `r2`. In general, you do not need to deal with cookies yourself when you are using a session with requests. Your code for `generating_data()` then becomes:

```
def generating_data():

    main_url='https://opencorporates.com/users/sign_in'    
    r1 = session.get(main_url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r1.text, 'html.parser')
    
    tokens = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name':'csrf-token'})
    token = tokens.get('content')
    print(f'token is : {token}')

    print('Login!')
    datas = {
        'utf8': '✓',
        'authenticity_token': token,
        'user[email]':'user',
        'user[password]':'pass',
        'submit':''
    }

    r2 = session.post('https://opencorporates.com/users/sign_in',headers=headers, data=datas)
    r3 = session.get('https://opencorporates.com/companies?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=above+and+beyond&commit=Go&jurisdiction_code=&utf8=%E2%9C%93&commit=Go&nbsp=&controller=searches&action=search_companies&inactive=false&mode=best_fields&search_fields[]=name&branch=false&nonprofit=&order=score', headers=headers)

f = open('./res.html', 'w+')
f.write(r3.text)
f.close
```